# BUG Some row in recyclerview not clickable inside view pager in tablet

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I have a layout with a view pager and consist of 2 fragments with recycler view
[image]

The first four-row is clickable, but the other is not clickable, it's happen in tablet mode.
In Phone mode, everything is working fine.

The strange thing is if the data is short(1 letter only), everything is clickable, but the data is long(more than 3 letters) then it's not clickable from row 4. The FAB button is working. I have already tried using physical tablet and emulated tablet.

I am using View Pager 2

Is this a bug? And how to solve this?

**Edited, My RecyclerView Adapter code**

```
private List<Craft> craftList;
private RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener;
private Context mContext;
public int selectedItem = -1;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView name ;
    public View container;
    private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

    public MyViewHolder(View view, RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
        super(view);
        mListener = listener;
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        container = view.findViewById(R.id.container);

        container.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        selectedItem = getBindingAdapterPosition();
        if(selectedItem!= RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
            mListener.OnButtonClick(v, getBindingAdapterPosition());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    void OnButtonClick(View view, int position);
}

public CraftAdapter(List<Craft> craftList, RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
    this.craftList = craftList;
    clickListener = listener;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.craft_item, parent, false);
    mContext = parent.getContext();
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView,clickListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Craft craft = craftList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(craft.getName());
    if(mContext.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet)){
        if(selectedItem == position){
            holder.container.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_blue);
        }
        else{
            holder.container.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return craftList.size();
}
```

Comment: Is this happening on the 'new' section too?

Comment: @Arthurghev what does "new" section means? It always happens on tablet(physical and emulated), but on phone it works fine. But on phone, there is only 1 fragment at the time, left & right fragments will show 1 by 1(list& detail)

Comment: @SusiS Can you share your recycler view adapter code?

Comment: @LucaPizzini Sure, I add it to my question

Comment: @SusiS in the picture there are 2 section 'new' and 'old', is this happening on the 'new' section too?

Comment: @Arthurghev Yes it is, I also try to use 3 fragments, and it happens to all of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting so much time. I finally found the root cause.

The cause is the layout using `LinearLayout` with `weight`. The `weight` make it not working, I think it's a bug. But I can solve it using `constraintlayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment android:name="CraftFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
            android:layout_weight="2" -->>This is the root cause
            android:layout_width="0dp" -->> This is the root cause
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/dark_grey2"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_fragment"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So I change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="CraftFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/detail_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"/>



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/list_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_grey2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/list_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/list_fragment"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```